# Sound problems with HDMI connection

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have a little question that isn't a really problem, but affects in someway when i want to watch some movie on my hdmi tv from my laptop.

So, what i ask you is since i've erased pulseaudio and have installed alsamixer, because this is the only way to stablished a properly sound connection in skype, i've lost the sound of my hdmi connection. The image works fine, but the sound have gone away...

there is some way to fix this? There is a Alsamixer HDMI plugin that fixes this issue?

I have a Acer Aspire 5542G, with AMD64 bits Turion (2,2ghz, 1Mb L2 cache), ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4570.

Oh, i have Ubuntu 11.04 Natty! Everything else works fine!! :D

Thx!

Jorge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-surround
```

Comment: Can you explain what the command does?

Comment: Please explain this further

Answer (score 3):

Try looking in sound preferences (click the volume applet and select Sound Settings).  From there, look in the output tab and make sure HDMI is selected.  If that doesn't work, try looking in the hardware tab, which should contain a dropdown, where you should see HDMI. Select that and it should work

Answer (score 2):

To expand [@Thuener's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/167711/105923), and the line

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-surround
```

`pactl` is the `PulseAudio Server Control`. The `set-card-profile` chooses a sound card, and if you have only one, the numeric index of your sound card is `0`. The last parameter `output:hdmi-surround` is self explanatory: "Set the sound cards output to hdmi-surround".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way to run this command automatically when an HDMI cable is connected and set it back to the laptop speaker when the cable gets disconnected? So far I always change the profile from the Sound preferences but that is not ideal.

Comment: Also, how can I get a list of the different profiles, like output:hdmi-surround? Thanks for the help!