# HDMI output sound

Tags: sound, hdmi, 14.04

I have no sound going to my TV via the HDMI output.  Running 14.04.  I have pulse audio and when I plug it into the TV, I get full video but no sound.  The sound bar is moving (in pulse audio) like it recognizes the sound but is not putting it to the TV (yes I made sure the TV sound was turned up).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46582/sound-problems-with-hdmi-connection/101478#101478) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/198022/no-sound-on-tv-via-hdmi/198025#198025) for suggestions.

Comment: I would first suggest updating you video driver especially if you have an ATI or NVidia card. I have been struggling with the same issue on a notebook with intel Iris pro 5200 Graphics and 14.04 and have yet to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer might be set to output audio on a different audio device. You can select your audio device from the sound settings menu, which can be accessed from your volume icon.

Answer (score 1):

Try the speaker test first from root:

```
speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000
```

If you can hear the sounds via HDMI output then go to sound setting and make sure the HDMI is highlighted.